# get_headers_curl with the format ($url,1)

Tags: php

the standard get_headers function has multiple format

```
get_headers($url);
get_headers($url,1);
```

im using the curl to set the timeout of the request so here is my function

```
function get_headers_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,        true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY,         true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,       3);

$r = curl_exec($ch);
$r = split("\n", $r);
return $r;
}
```

i have tried

```
get_headers_curl($url,1)
```

no results

so please tell me how to make the second format like

```
get_headers($url,1)
```

best regards

Comment: i want to get Array ( [0] ,[Server],[Content-legnh]) and not Array( [0],[1],[2]) thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  the  `curl_getinfo()`
function.

Comment: curl_getinfo(); it has not get headers

Comment: You can pass a variable to set which header do you want. CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT